# How can I change the action bar colour with animation?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation

Whenever the colour scheme changes on the server it should also change on the app. So far I've managed to make the action bar change its colour. The only problem is that when the notification is received, the colour changes instantaneously. Is there a way to animate a transition from the old colour to the new one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this example both color (Statusbar, Toolbar) will be changed (with animation ), you will need to modify it a bit to suit your own needs.

```
        Integer colorFrom = Color.parseColor(ThemeColor.getPrevColor());
        Integer colorTo = Color.parseColor(ThemeColor.getColor());
        Integer colorStatusFrom = Color.parseColor(ThemeColor.getPrevStatusColor());
        Integer colorStatusTo = Color.parseColor(ThemeColor.getStatusColor());
        ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
        ValueAnimator colorStatusAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorStatusFrom, colorStatusTo);

        colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });

        colorStatusAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                }
                if (currentapiVersion == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    tintManager.setStatusBarTintColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                }
            }
        });

        colorAnimation.setDuration(1300);
        colorAnimation.setStartDelay(0);
        colorAnimation.start();
        colorStatusAnimation.setDuration(1300);
        colorStatusAnimation.setStartDelay(0);
        colorStatusAnimation.start();
```

Comment: What is "tintManager"?

Comment: It's old third party library for tinting status bar on  pre-Lollipop. https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint